# Hello guys, I'm getting an error when trying to store an image got from a html form using multer in express js

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I'm working on a small app in which I wanted to store an image got from an input field of type file, I followed the guide on the multer docs but when I try to submit my form i get this error Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory.

Basing on the code, the image was supposed to be picked and stored in a /images folder in my from my root directory

My App.js file

```
const multer = require('multer');

const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, path.join(__dirname, 'images'));
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + '-' + file.originalname);
    } 
});

app.use(multer({storage: fileStorage}).single('image'));
```

my ejs view

```
<form class="product-form" action="/admin/add-product" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-control">
        <label for="image">Image</label>
        <input
           type="file" 
           name="image" 
           id="image" 
         >
   </div>
   <button class="btn" type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

my package.js

```
{
  "name": "full-recap",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "recap",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.7.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.1",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "connect-mongodb-session": "^3.1.1",
    "csurf": "^1.11.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "ejs": "^3.1.8",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-handlebars": "^6.0.6",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "express-validator": "^6.14.2",
    "mongodb": "^4.12.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.8.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1"
  }
}
```

and the full error i get is "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Dunia Dunia\Desktop\Coding my career\Nodejs\Full-Recap\images\2023-01-05T22:58:24.937Z-firstpic.jpg'"

Comment: It looks like the problem is that the /images directory doesn't exist in your root directory!!! did you create the folder where the images will be uploaded to ?

Comment: No, I don’t think that is the problem because I created that folder and if the folder wasn’t there normally multer would create it on the fly

Comment: is the images folder in the root of your project ? because for example if the folder is in public/images you should change your code !

Comment: No, It is in the root of my project

Answer (score 1):

Well, I got help from someone and I was able to solve this problem.

This code the way it is structured above should work on MAC but on windows there is a function to add to the filename definition

```js
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, path.join(__dirname, './images/'));
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, '-') + '-' + file.originalname);
    }
});
```

After the `toISOString()` there should be added the replace function